# Transpiling a Node.js + TypeScript app with Babel: why it's not using optional chaining?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, babeljs

I am experimenting with Babel to understand better how it works. I created a simple API with Node.js and TypeScript. Everything works fine when I transpile code and the server runs properly. I have a question though: in node `v14.15.3` optional chaining is supported, so why when I build with:

```
rm -rf build/ && babel src --source-maps --extensions '.js,.ts,.tsx' --ignore '**/*.test.ts' -d build
```

no matter what version of node I'm running in the shell (by using nvm - `v12.18.3` or `v14.15.3`) the following line

```
console.log(x?.ciao ?? 10)
```

it's always transpiled to

```
console.log((_x$ciao = x === null || x === void 0 ? void 0 : x.ciao) !== null && _x$ciao !== void 0 ? _x$ciao : 10);
```

I would expect it to use `.?` and `??` in the transpiled code since they're supported. What am I missing?

I also tried to remove the `@babel/preset-typescript` preset and did a test with a single file, but yet the code is transpiled as above.

My `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-typescript", ["@babel/preset-env", { "shippedProposals": true }]],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": "./src",
        "alias": {
          "@root": ["./"],
          "@src": ["./src"]
        },
        "extensions": [".js", ".ts"]
      }
    ]
  ],
  "sourceMaps": true
}
```

Comment: the point of babel is to compile code that works in browsers, it's re-writing the code like that so that it's backwards-compatible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work use `"targets": { "node": 14 }` as in the following `.babelrc` example. This will not transpile `.?` or `??` since they are supported in node 14.x.

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": { "node": 14 }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": "./src",
        "alias": {
          "@root": ["./"],
          "@src": ["./src"]
        },
        "extensions": [".js", ".ts"]
      }
    ]
  ],
  "sourceMaps": true
}
```